# Python convert hexa to string

Tags: python, string, hex

I want to write something like:

```
str="0xdeadbeef"
```

so that in the memory, where str is stored, the binary represntation will be "deadbeef".

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Do you want to store a string, or to store the data in another format, and print it as hexa?  (also, you have a typo: deadbeef vs deadbeaf)

Comment: Why do you want to do it? This is Python, not ASM

Comment: The binary representation can't be deadbeef. I assume you mean the hexadecimal representation? `x = 0xdeadbeef`

Comment: I want to store a string, and I want that the characters will be represented by 0xdeadbeef.

Comment: Of course, the hexadecimal representation.

Comment: To make it more clear, instead of writing str="ABCD" I want to write something like str="0x41424344" (where 41 is the representation of "A" and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> instead of writing `str="ABCD"` I want to write something like `str="0x41424344"`

It *sounds* like you're looking for

```
s = '\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
```

but why?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted.

Comment: I want this because I don't want to write text to a file, but an address.